# How to focus the Accordion top header when we click on that

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

[**JS FIDDLE OF MY ACCORDION**](https://jsfiddle.net/3ah26cvq/)

I am trying to focus on header or first div which is inside of accordion but it is not working.

In the js fiddle by default html is active and it consist of 11 questions in it.
And now **PHP** by default it is collapsed and when we click on it it will open and **HTML** will collapse.

My problem is when i click on `PHP` it is showing the last question in my case it is showing **11th question of PHP**, Actually it should show the **first quuestion of PHP** how can i achieve it..?

Please see the js fiddle which i have shared.

i have tried with 3 different ways but none are working:

```
$("#panelForPHP").click(function(){     $("#accordionPHP").focus(); });
$("#panelForPHP").click(function(){     $("#collapsePHP1").focus(); });
$("#panelForPHP").click(function(){     $("#panelForPHP").focus(); });
```

Comment: yeah it is expanding but on page i can able to see the last part i want to see the top part.

Answer (score 1):

To scroll up to top of panel-body

```
$('#accordionMain').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {

    var panel = $(this).find('.in');

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: panel.offset().top
    });
});
```

To scroll up to panel-heading,

```
$('#accordionMain').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {

    var panel = $(this).find('.in');

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: panel.offset().top -55
    });
});
```

Comment: it is working but can you please tell how can i show the category as well.  i can see that your code is triggering `top` i want to trigger `category  in my case `PHP` should be visible as top.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed I have edited the answer to fit best with your requirements. Hope it works!

Comment: it is not working it is big issue because when i open question 11 it is showing 1 st question in your both cases. @chandan-rg

Answer (score 1):

The hierarchical structure of accordions is making the issue little complex in your case. When you open 'question 11' of 'PHP' it scrolls to the first element with '.in' class. The '.in' class is inserted by bootstrap scripts to the active panel body. When 'question 11' is clicked there are two active panel bodies, first containing 11 questions under PHP and second containing answer of question 11.

In this scenario, you need to capture the last panel body with '.in' class.

```
var panel = $(this).find('.in').last();
```

If you close the PHP(parent accordion) leaving the questions(child accordion) open, and open parent accordion again it'll scroll to last open child accordion as it is the last element with '.in' class.