# Bootstrap Accordin Force to Show opened accordion

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I am trying to focus on header or first div which is inside of accordion but it is not working.

In the js fiddle by default, **HTML** is active and it consists of 11 questions in it. And now PHP by default it is collapsed and when we click on it, it will open and **HTML** will collapse.

My problem is when I click on PHP it is showing the last question in my case it is showing the **11th question of PHP**, Actually it should show the **first question** of **PHP** how can I achieve it..?

Please see the js fiddle which I have shared.

```
$("#panelForPHP").click(function(){     $("#accordionPHP").focus(); });
$("#panelForPHP").click(function(){     $("#collapsePHP1").focus(); });
$("#panelForPHP").click(function(){     $("#panelForPHP").focus(); });
```

[**JS FIDDLE OF MY ACCORDION**](https://jsfiddle.net/3ah26cvq/)

i have tried with 3 different ways but none are working:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to focus the Accordion top header when we click on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44226885/how-to-focus-the-accordion-top-header-when-we-click-on-that)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
$('#accordionMain').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {

    var panel = $(this).find('.in');

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: panel.offset().top -55
    });
});
```